# C# Reactive Extensions - Iterate through items of IObservable<List<Item>>

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I've started to play around with the `rx` version of **C#** recently and am wondering how it's possible to solve the following problem:

I'm using [refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) to get a list of items from a server via:

```
[Get("/items")]
IObservable<List<Item>> GetItems();
```

I would like to process each item afterwards, but I didn't find out how to do that. I know in RxJava there is an operator called `flatMapIterable()` which allows me to process each item, but I didn't find something similar for **C#**.

Thanks

Comment: sorry, did it now, thx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, you need the [`.SelectMany`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html).

```
[Get("/items")]
IObservable<List<Item>> GetItems() 
{
    observable.SelectMany(t => t);
}
```

In the [Rx.NET repo](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/2252cb4edbb25aca12005b9a912311edd2f095f3/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/SelectMany.cs), you can look at the implementation of the source - if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

You need `SelectMany();`

```
IObservable<List<Item>> observable = new List<List<Item>>().ToObservable();
var flattened = observable.SelectMany(i => i);
```